# Script does not working for loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I created a form with checkbox + wrapper, i.e :

```
<form>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1">
  </dv>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="3">
  </div>
</form>
```

and this toggle check is working:

```
$(".input-wrapper").on("click", function () { 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
 });
```

But when I load other checkbox from ajax, i.e:

```
$.post(
     '/my/url',
     {...my data...},
      function(data){
           if(data != 'failed'){
               //return new checkbox + wrapper too and append it at the end of the form
                $('form').append(data);
           }
      }
 );
```

the Toggle check is not working just for the loaded/appended element.

How to fix this ? **how to properly create a script that affect all the element even for the loaded one ?**

thanks.

Comment: Check: http://jsfiddle.net/hhg7N/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this slight modification:

```
$("form").on("click", ".input-wrapper", function () { 
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
});
```

and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're binding the click listener will bind to all `.input-wrapper` elements currently  in the DOM.

You may either bind the new ones for clicks separately, or delegate the listener to a parent object that will stay in the DOM (e.g. `$(document).on("click", ".input-wrapper", function (){//Do Stuff});`)